Transaction problem
I do have a account in which I have over 1600 USDT and when I required funds for trading I tried to send the funds from phantom wallet to kucoin then it said transaction disabled. I thought it was problem with the exchange wallet so I tried transferring to trust Wallet it is still the same . TRANSACTION DISABLED ***Your address was not able to transact with phantom. Please help .

please contact phantom support settings > help & support.
